# reload data in modal after another modal close angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.3

So the issue is here, I have a modal and another modal.

the first modal has a table which is to be filled by the other modal but it doesn't update the view.

[first modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U15Ug.png)

[another modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX3Qf.png)

but when I close all modals then open it again the values are changed to what I saved.

My Question is how to refresh or reload the data in table not the modal after saving the other modal by using angularjs and without closing all modals please help.

Comment: Once you add the package try to call the method which loads package list else you can load package list method using some time interval by using $timeout or $ interval

Comment: uhm how to use $timeout or $interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- 1)

  If your modals are components, you can add pass bindings to it.
- 1a)

  Both modal may use 2-way data binding to work on the same object (not recommended)
- 1b)

You can use bindings '<' (one-way) and '&(expression) for callback. On modal can trigger the callback to update the data in the parent and the parent will push it to second modal via '<' binding

- 2)

  You can make a angular service for communication and where:
  modal A registers hist callback function and modalB will call a service moethod which will trigger modal A callback. Something like publish subscribe pattern
- 3)

  You can try to hack it with $scope.parent.$apply() called from one of modals, so it will recalculate all the stuff from it's parent

Answer (score 0):

you could try like below..

```
function TestController($scope, $timeout, dialog){
//simulate $http get
$timeout(function() {
   var httpGetData = Data;
   dialog.close({ isInitialized: true, data: httpGetData });
}, 3000);
}
```

else

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#myModal').fadeIn(200);
} 30000); // milliseconds
```

Comment: its not working.. everytime I add or update the package table it doesn't reload but when I close all modals then click the event that triggered the modal it updates.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution, I just reload the function that I use when opening the first modal. thank you for the answer.